# application has stopped after running the application

Tags: android

I am trying to make loging page but this code not run properly 
application afer run tym says unfortunately has stopped i don't no why .i am new in android any one plzz help .i am so frustrate

database file!!

```
 public class RegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="registrationDataBase.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="registrationTable";
    public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String PHONE="phone";
    public static final String ADDRESS="address";

    private static final String QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(id integer primary key autoincrement"+NAME+"not null"+PASSWORD+"not null"+PHONE+"not null"+ADDRESS+"not null)";

    RegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);

    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

        db.execSQL(QUERY);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void setName(String nam){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME,nam);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

send data from this file file

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText mEditTextName,mEditTextPassword,mEditTextPhone,mEditTextAddress;
        Button mButtonRegistration;
        String getName,getPassword,getPhone,getAddress;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditTextName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEditTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        mEditTextPhone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mEditTextAddress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        mButtonRegistration=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        mButtonRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getName=mEditTextName.getText().toString();
                getPassword=mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();
                getPhone=mEditTextPhone.getText().toString();
                getAddress=mEditTextAddress.getText().toString();

                RegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile objOfRegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile=new RegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile(getBaseContext());

                objOfRegistrationDetailsDataBaseFile.setName(getName);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the related contents of the Logcat

Comment: @Pooya i am new in android stdio how can i post contents of logcat

Comment: In the QUERY statement for creating table you didn't define any type of the columns name, password, phone and address. Also separate the columns using space or comma

Comment: @PushpamKumar read http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: @Kanchan Chowdhury thank bro u save m time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define any type of the columns. There is also spacing problems. To create table modify your query statement as following:

```
private static final String QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (id integer primary key autoincrement, "+NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+PASSWORD+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+PHONE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ADDRESS+"TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Also modify the onUpgrade() method as following:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```